# different between @Model and @model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Basically I'm doing a test caused by one of excpetion.

By using `return View(list_a`) in controller I passed a list into my view, On my View page, the code is like:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "KYC_Home";
}
@using UniBlue.Models;
@model UniBlue.Models.KYC
...
@foreach(KYC a in Model)
...
```

there will be an exception says:

```
CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'UniBlue.Models.KYC' because 'UniBlue.Models.KYC' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

But, when i changed my code to 
@Model
Page looks good but on the title it shows:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UniBlue.Models.KYC] UniBlue.Models.KYC
```

as regular HTML text

Can anybody tell me why this happened? What should I do to remove the strange title line?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One is used to declare the strong type that the model is, and the other is used to access the model itself.

The following says that the strong type used for the model is `UniBlue.Models.KYC`.

```
@model UniBlue.Models.KYC
```

This basically declares the 'variable' `Model` as that type.  It's akin to doing the following:

```
UniBlue.Models.KYC Model;
```

`Model` is a variable, `@model` is a keyword saying what type `Model` will be.

Your error is because you've declared `Model` as KYC, but KYC is not enumerable.  You're using it in a `foreach` expecting an `IEnumerable<UniBlue.Models.KYC>` which is not the case.

If your model is truly a list, then use

```
@model IEnumerable<UniBlue.Models.KYC>
```

Comment: Good point! But what's the reason it runs when I write like:  Model UniBlue.Models.KYC, no value assigned to the Model itself right?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: but instead of writing "model UniBlue.Models.KYC", I used 'Model UniBlue.Models.KYC' and it also ran successfully and display well, so I still don't know why that didn't cause any exceptions and get the list data

Comment: It's possible that `@model` and `@Model` may be interchangable when declaring the model type.

Comment: Mn.. so  the point of setting the strong type in a view is to tell it which param type the controller pass through, if I pass a list, I should declare model as a List<Models.KYC>, am I right?

Comment: Yes, it should match whatever type is being passed out of your action (such as `return View(model);`

Comment: Right answer!!! Thank you for helping me, you at least save me one week on that, I really appreciate your precious time!
P.S., have any good article on creating and designing model?

Comment: "@model is a keyword saying what type Model will be." -- good mention!

Answer (score 7):

@model denotes the type of a variable you refer as @Model

```
@model string

@Model.ToUpper(); // works as @Model is of type string
```