# @Model vs Model in a view file

Tags: c#, .net, razor

In this view file all of the PageName values render the same. Why is this so? I understand that @model declares the model type. I understand that @Model will render model onto the screen. What I'm confused about is why @Model.PageName would match Model.PageName in the html helper.

```
@model Pages

<div class="moduleName">@Model.PageName</div>
<div class="moduleName">@Html.Raw(@Model.PageName)</div>
<div class="moduleName">@Html.Raw(Model.PageName)</div>
```

There are lots of similar question on SO but not couldn't find one that quite matches this. For example, [@Model vs @model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752749/different-between-model-and-model).

Sorry if it's something simple! I see the @ symbol as also denoting an escape-free string literal and also when naming a variable that's also a reserved keyword. Not sure how those would apply here.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in that context.  Identifiers in C# can be prepended with an `@` to distinguish them from keywords (e.g. you can declare a variable named `@class` but not `class`).  The `@` sign is not part of the identifier so `@MyVar` and `MyVar` are the same identifier.

The `@` before `Html` is a razor escape character that changes the context from HTML to C# code-behind. Once you're there, the `@` before `Model` does nothing because it binds to the static `Model` property of the view, just like `Model` does.

So you can interpret each line as follows:

```
<div class="moduleName">--begin C# expression-- Model.PageName --end C# expression--</div>
<div class="moduleName">--begin C# expression-- Html.Raw(Model.PageName) --end C# expression--</div>
<div class="moduleName">--begin C# expression-- Html.Raw(Model.PageName) --end C# expression--</div>
```