# Asp.net Core MVC View @model line is emitted to browser

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Hi I'm new to MVC so this might be a dumb question. In this application, when I go to details view, there is the Item class full reference path "MyApp.Models.Item", with the first line which is the @Model Item, shown in the browser. Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

The View:

```
@Model Item

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}
@{
Layout = "";
}
<div>
</div>
```

The controller:

```
    // GET: Item/Details/5
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var item = await _context.Item
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(item);
    }
```

If in the view I replace the

> @Model Item

With

> @Model MyApp.Models.Item

It will become:

[image]

So I know the second string is from the "@Model Item" line, but I don't know how it is emitted to browser. And I don't know where the first "MyApp.Models.Item" comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible that for declaring your view object model you need to use @model, not @Model.

The answer in this question describes it better:
[different between @Model and @model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752749/different-between-model-and-model)